# Automatically create i18n directory for VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to understand the workflow presented in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/i18n-sample for localizing Visual Studio Code extensions.

I cannot figure out **how the i18n directory gets created to begin with**, as well as how the set of string keys in that directory get maintained over time.

There is one line in the README.md which says "You could have created this folder by hand, or you could have used the vscode-nls-dev tool to extract it."...how would one use vscode-nls-dev tool to extract it?

**What I Understand**

I understand that you can use `vscode-nls`, and wrap strings like this: `localize("some.key", "My String")` to pick up the localized version of that string at runtime.

I am pretty sure I understand that `vscode-nls-dev` is used at build time to substitute the content of files in the `i18n` directory into the  transpiled JavaScript code, as well as creating files like `out/extension.nls.ja.json`

**What is missing**

Surely it is not expected that: for every `file.ts` file in your project you create an `i18n/lang/out/file.i18n.json` for every lang you support...and then keep the set of keys in that file up to date manually with every string change.

I am assuming that there is some process which automatically goes "are there any `localize("key", "String")` calls in file.ts for new keys not yet in file.i18n.json? If so, add those keys with some untranslated values". What is that process?

Comment: Note that proposed in vscode 1.72 is a new way to use and generate localized strings, see  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#localization-as-part-of-the-api - there is a lot of information there, too much to copy/paste to an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out, referencing https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/issues/74

This is built to work if you use Transifex for your translator. At the bare minimum you need to use `.xlf` files as your translation file format.

I think that this is best illustrated with an example, so lets say you wanted to get the [sample project](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/i18n-sample) working **after you had deleted the i18n folder**

- Step 1: Clone that project, and delete the i18n directory
- Step 2: Modify the [gulp file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/i18n-sample/gulpfile.js) so that the `compile` function also generates nls metadata files in the `out` directory. Something like:

```
    function compile(buildNls) {
        var r = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(tsProject()).js
            .pipe(buildNls ? nls.rewriteLocalizeCalls() : es.through())
            .pipe(buildNls ? nls.createAdditionalLanguageFiles(languages, 'i18n', 'out') : es.through())
            .pipe(buildNls ? nls.bundleMetaDataFiles('ms-vscode.node-debug2', 'out') : es.through())
            .pipe(buildNls ? nls.bundleLanguageFiles() : es.through())
```

- Step 3: Run the `gulp build` command. This will generate several necessary metadata files in the `out/` directory
- Step 4: Create and run a new gulp function to export the necessarry translations to the xlf file. Something like:

```
    gulp.task('export-i18n', function() {
        return gulp.src(['package.nls.json', 'out/nls.metadata.header.json', 'out/nls.metadata.json'])
            .pipe(nls.createXlfFiles("vscode-extensions", "node-js-debug2"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join('vscode-translations-export')));
    }
```

- Step 5: Get the resulting xlf file translated. Or, add some dummy values. I cant find if/where there is documentation for the file format needed, but this worked for me (for the extension):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
      <file original="package" source-language="en" target-language="ja" datatype="plaintext"><body>
        <trans-unit id="extension.sayHello.title">
          <source xml:lang="en">Hello</source>
          <target>JA_Hello</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="extension.sayBye.title">
          <source xml:lang="en">Bye</source>
          <target>JA_Bye</target>
        </trans-unit>
      </body></file>
      <file original="out/extension" source-language="en" target-language="ja" datatype="plaintext"><body>
        <trans-unit id="sayHello.text">
          <source xml:lang="en">Hello</source>
          <target>JA_Hello</target>
        </trans-unit>
      </body></file>
      <file original="out/command/sayBye" source-language="en" target-language="ja" datatype="plaintext"><body>
        <trans-unit id="sayBye.text">
          <source xml:lang="en">Bye</source>
          <target>JA_Bye</target>
        </trans-unit>>
      </body></file>
    </xliff>
```

- Step 6: Stick that file in some known location, let's say `/path/to/translation.xlf`. Then add/run another new gulp task to import the translation. Something like:

```
    gulp.task('i18n-import', () => {
        return es.merge(languages.map(language => {
            console.log(language.folderName)
            return gulp.src(["/path/to/translation.xlf"])
                .pipe(nls.prepareJsonFiles())
                .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join('./i18n', language.folderName)));
        }));
    });
```

- Step 7: Run the `gulp build` again.

The `i18n/` directory should now be recreated correctly! Running the same build/export/translate/import/build steps will pick up any new changes to the `localize()` calls in your TypeScript code

Obviously this is not perfect, there are a lot of hardcoded paths and such, but hopefully it helps out anyone else who hits this issue.